# Why am I getting error suspended ActivityNotFoundException?

Tags: android

```
package com.basic.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class androidbasics extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    int logoTimer=0;
                    while(logoTimer<5000){
                    sleep(500);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer +100;
                    }

                startActivity(new Intent("com.basic.android.MENU"));    
            }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                finish();
                        }
            }        
        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.basic.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".androidbasics"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".menu"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.basic.android.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity android:name=".DisplayOne"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.basic.android.DISPLAYONE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TutorialTwo"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.basic.android.TUTORIALTWO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                  <activity android:name=".Sweet"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.basic.android.SWEET" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TutorialFour"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"                
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.basic.android.TUTORIALFOUR" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".TutorialThree"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.basic.android.TUTORIALTHREE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFALT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
</manifest>
```

Errors:

```
06-29 11:57:56.356: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
06-29 11:58:11.466: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
06-29 11:58:15.035: ERROR/BatteryService(67): usbOnlinePath not found
06-29 11:58:15.035: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryVoltagePath not found
06-29 11:58:15.045: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryTemperaturePath not found
06-29 11:58:15.125: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(67): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
06-29 11:58:30.165: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
06-29 11:58:30.165: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
06-29 11:58:30.595: ERROR/System(67): Failure starting core service
06-29 11:58:30.595: ERROR/System(67): java.lang.SecurityException
06-29 11:58:30.595: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
06-29 11:58:30.595: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
06-29 11:58:30.595: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
06-29 11:58:30.595: ERROR/System(67):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
06-29 11:58:33.846: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
06-29 11:58:33.866: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
06-29 11:58:33.896: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
06-29 11:58:33.935: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
06-29 11:58:33.946: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
06-29 11:58:42.016: ERROR/ThrottleService(67): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
06-29 11:58:44.726: ERROR/logwrapper(141): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-29 11:58:44.826: ERROR/logwrapper(142): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-29 11:58:44.925: ERROR/logwrapper(144): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67): ANR in com.android.settings
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider (has extras) }
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67): Load: 2.74 / 0.7 / 0.23
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67): CPU usage from 17983ms to 1294ms ago:
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   system_server: 34% = 20% user + 13% kernel / faults: 7292 minor 16 major
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   adbd: 18% = 1% user + 17% kernel / faults: 11 minor
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   bootanimation: 7% = 5% user + 1% kernel / faults: 517 minor
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 82 minor
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   kswapd0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   netd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 21 minor
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 49 minor
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   events/0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   servicemanager: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 33 minor
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):  +ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):  +m.android.phone: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):  +ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67):  +ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
06-29 11:58:58.785: ERROR/ActivityManager(67): TOTAL: 100% = 47% user + 48% kernel + 1% irq + 2% softirq
06-29 11:59:37.867: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(67): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
```

Comment: -1. For editing this code third time. (Also making me to format your code for three time)

Comment: You need to ask a question - you have not placed a question mark in your text, so there isn't a question yet.  And you will learn to format your code, please.  Also, you need to learn how to minimize the material you add to a question; I'm not sure this is minimal (there are a lot of error messages - I'm not sure whether the code can be reduced further.  You should probably also explain what you are _trying_ to do.

Comment: this question is same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516667/what-is-it-my-code-problem why are you asking the same question two time with different username.

Answer (score 1):

change..(see DEFALT change to DEFAULT in category)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in mismatch in defining activity name.
In manifest you have defined the activity name is `menu` not `MENU`

```
<activity android:name=".menu"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

But in code `startActivity(new Intent("com.basic.android.MENU"));` you want to start an activity MENU whcich is not defined because in manifest menu is defined but MENU is not defined

The activity name is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Before calling startActivity(new Intent("com.basic.android.MENU")) cancel your logoTimer

like

```
logoTimer.cancel();
startActivity(new Intent("com.basic.android.MENU"))
```

//

```
public void toCallActivity() {
    TimerTask startNewActivity;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();


        startNewActivity = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                                             timer.cancel();
startActivity(new Intent("com.basic.android.MENU"));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block


                        }

                    }
                });

            }

        };

        timer.schedule(startNewActity, 0,5000);

    }
```

Comment: Unreachable catch block for InterruptedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Comment: I think what are you trying to do can be done very easily in another way.Using TimerTask and a Timer

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in mismatch in defining activity name. In manifest you have defined the activity name is menu not MENU

```
<activity android:name=".menu"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Android Studio is case sensitive, so this should work.